# Is $k=1$ in this exercise

Tags: real-analysis

I did this exercise

**Exercise 4.3.10.**  Let $f $ be a function defined on $\mathbb R$ such that $f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b) $ for all $a,b \in \mathbb R$.

(a) Show that $f(0)=0$ and $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$

(b) Show that if $f$ is continuous at $0$ then $f$ is continuous everywhere

(c) Let $k = f(1)$. Show that $f(n) = kn$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ and then show that $f(z) = kz$ for $z \n \mathbb Z$. Now prove that $f(q) = kq$ for $q \in \mathbb Q$.

(d) Use (b) and (c) to conclude that $f(x) = kx$.

The problem is: I show $(c)$ part for rational numbers like this:

$k=f(n/n) = f(n)f(1/n)$ (because $f$ is additve) and then $f(1/n) = 1/n$. It follows that $f$ is the identity on $\mathbb Q$. Then because it is continuous it is the identity on $\mathbb R$.

But, in $(d)$ it should follow that it is a linear function through the origin. Can $k \neq 1$?

Comment: Would you mind retyping the problem statement in TeX? Images are not searchable and thus provide no benefit for other users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof of (c) seems wrong. It should be:
$$k=f(n/n)=n\cdot f(1/n)$$
so that $f(1/n)=k/n$ and $f(m/n)=k\cdot m/n$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $k$ can be $\ne1$, and in that respect your first proof is off by a constant factor. Just check that $f(x)=0$ is a solution, trivially.